# Progress bar will start if user click in advertise

Tags: laravel, click, progress-bar

'''<!doctype html>

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"
      href="{{ asset(imagePath()['logoIcon']['path'] .'/favicon.png') }}"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    @php
        $activeTemplateTrue = activeTemplate(true);
    @endphp
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset($activeTemplateTrue.'frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset($activeTemplateTrue.'frontend/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <title>{{ $general->sitename(__($page_title) ?? '') }}</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/iziToast.min.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/js/iziToast.min.js') }}"></script>

    <style>
        .clear-msg {
            height: 100vh;
        }
        #myProgress {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        #myBar {
            width: 10%;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #00bcd4;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
            color: white;
        }
        #confirm{
            color:white;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        .inputcaptcha{
            width:60px;
        }
        .btn{
            margin-top: -4px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
                margin-top: 15px;
            }
            .container{
                display: flex !important;
                justify-content: center !important;
            }
        }
        @media (max-width: 320px) {
            .row{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .btn{
                margin-top: 5px;

            }
        }
        .adFram{
            border: 0;
            position:absolute; top: 14%;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%
        }
        .adBody{
            position:absolute;
            top:30%;
            left:40%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    @if(session()->has('notify'))
        <script>
            alert('Your calculation is incorrect');
        </script>
    @endif
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary p-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="myProgress">
                    <div id="myBar">0%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active row">
                    <span id="inputcaptchahidden" class="d-none">
                        <form action="{{route('user.ptc.confirm',Crypt::encryptString($ptc->id.'|'.auth()->user()->id))}}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <input  name="num1" id="cap_number_1" class="inputcaptcha"  value="{{ $n1 }}" type="text" readonly>
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail2 text-white"> + </label>
                            <input  name="num2" id="cap_number_2" class="inputcaptcha" value="{{ $n2 }}" type="text"   readonly>


                            <input type="hidden" name="res" value="{{ encrypt($res)}}">

                            <label for="exampleInputEmail2 text-white">=</label>
                            <input name="result" type="number" class="inputcaptcha" id="cap_result" required> &nbsp;
                            <button type="button" id="confirm" class="btn btn-warning">@lang('Confirm Earn')</button>
                        </form>
                    </span>

                    <a type="button" id="loading" class="btn btn-danger text-white btn-md" disabled>
                        @lang('Loading Ads')
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        "use strict";

        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return ;
        });

        (function ($) {
            $('#cap_result').on('input',function(){
                var val1 = document.getElementById("cap_number_1").value;
                var val2 = document.getElementById("cap_number_2").value;
                var val3 = document.getElementById("cap_result").value;
                var confirmButton = document.getElementById("confirm");

                var sum = parseInt(+val1 + +val2);

                if(sum==val3){
                    confirmButton.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
                    confirmButton.className = "btn btn-success";
                }else{
                    confirmButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                    confirmButton.className = "btn btn-danger";
                }
            });

            function move() {

                var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                var width = 0;

                var id = setInterval(frame, {{$ptc->duration * 10}});

                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 100) {
                        var confirmButton = document.getElementById("loading");
                        confirmButton.remove();
                        var captchaInputHidden =  document.getElementById("inputcaptchahidden");
                        captchaInputHidden.classList.remove("d-none");
                        clearInterval(id);

                    }else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        elem.innerHTML = width + '%';
                    }
                }
            }

            window.onload = move;



        })(jQuery);

        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
            if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
                document.body.innerHTML = `
                           <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-items-center clear-msg">
                                <h3 class="text-danger text-center">@lang('Sorry you can\'t go anywhere from this tab while viewing an ad')</h3>
                            </div>
                        `;
            }
        });





    </script>

    @if($ptc->ads_type==1)
        <iframe src="{{ $ptc->ads_body }}" class="adFram"></iframe>
    @elseif($ptc->ads_type==2)
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <img  src="{{ asset('assets/images/ptcimages/'.$ptc->ads_body) }}" class="w-100">
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="adBody">
        @php echo $ptc->ads_body @endphp
    </div>
    @endif

    <script src="{{asset($activeTemplateTrue.'users/js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

I have this code in my laravel script ad show page.
when this page fully load the progress bar automatically starting. So users dont need to click on advertise to start the progress bar. So they can put the eaqual of captcha and submit without clicking the advertise.

**Now i want if user click on advertise only then the progress bar will start. Can anyone help me with this code please. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
You should remove window.onload = move and add a click event listener like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
                $('#advertise').on('click',function(){
                var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                var width = 0;

                var id = setInterval(frame, {{$ptc->duration * 10}});

                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 100) {
                        var confirmButton = document.getElementById("loading");
                        confirmButton.remove();
                        var captchaInputHidden =  document.getElementById("inputcaptchahidden");
                        captchaInputHidden.classList.remove("d-none");
                        clearInterval(id);

                    }else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        elem.innerHTML = width + '%';
                    }
                }
                });
            });
```

Comment: I removed window.onload = move
And i added the listener event like you gave. But now progress bar is not loading  after clicking the advertise on the page. Progress bar is stuck on 0%

Comment: I replaced the new code with your previous code but its same. After clicking the advertise its stuck progress bar on 0. I copy your code as it is.

Comment: your clickable advertise has id="advertise" ?

Comment: I am sorry . But i cant find the id. I gave full page code above. I got a class="adbody" but i cant find the id. Can you please help me with this

Comment: Where you click you should add id="advertise". for example if it's a button, image or hyperlink should has id to call JS function.

Comment: I added a id="myptc" in my script. Now its start loading when i click script element border. But i need progress bar will start when 1. If there is a video in script when i play the video progress bar will start. 2. If there is a link in script , when i click the link progress bar will start. Can u help me with this please.

Comment: @SanaulDey What do you mean will start when 1? Please explain your last comment.

Comment: I added a id="myptc" in my script. Now its start loading when i click script element border. But i need progress bar will start when If there is a video in script when i play the video progress bar will start. Or If there is a link in script , when i click the link progress bar will start. Can u help me with this please